# De-Broglie Wavelength and the Pilot Wave Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-interpretations, matter, bohmian-mechanics

I researched a lot of questions on De-Broglie waves on this website and discovered a dense fog of confusion amongst everyone. Louis De-Broglie proposed "Matter Waves" and a simple equation describing the wavelength of these waves. Majority of the questions about interpretations of De-Broglie wavelength on this website have answers stating that De-Broglie waves are described as probability waves through an abstract space possessing no physical meaning and that the idea is later refined mathematically into Schrodinger's Wave Equation.

My question is how does this relate to the De-Broglie Bohm Theory or the Pilot Wave Theory. According to some web resources, De-Broglie believed "Matter Waves" to be real waves and this idea was later picked up by David Bohm in his Pilot Wave Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics. The interpretation is quite contrary to the probabilistic description of the wave and introduces a real guiding wave for the quantum particles. So to summarise everything, what exactly are De-Broglie waves? If they are described as waves of probability with no physical meaning then why the Pilot Wave Theory is also referred to as De-Broglie Bohm Theory? If they are real, physical waves why are stack exchange users describing them as waves of probability?

Comment: Read [up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_wave_theory) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie–Bohm_theory). Informal answers here cannot fix things.